# creating custom archive template within plugin for custom post type using archive_template filter

Tags: plugin-development, templates, archive-template

I'm trying to create category and tags archive template from my plugin that has custom post type 'product'.

I used the below code to display search results in template file located at `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/inc/templates/product-search.php'`.

```
function template_chooser( $template ){

global $post;  

$plugin_root_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/product-plugin/';

if( is_search() && get_post_type($post) == 'product' ){

    return $plugin_root_dir.'/inc/templates/domain-search.php';

} else {
    return $template;
}
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'template_chooser' );
```

Which loads the search template file perfectly.

But when I try to load the archive-product.php (see below code) file using archive filter `archive_template` as mentioned in [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/archive_template). It simply loads installed theme's archive template with 'No Posts Found'.

below is the code to load archive_template for categories with post type `product`:

```
function get_custom_post_type_template( $archive_template ) {
 global $post;
 $plugin_root_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/product-plugin/';

 if ( is_post_type_archive ( 'product' ) ) {
      $archive_template = $plugin_root_dir.'/inc/templates/archive-product.php'
 }
 return $archive_template;
}

add_filter( 'archive_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' ) ;
```

I tried various answers online but result is same. could you please show me a way to create a custom archive template for a custom post type created inside a plugin?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: What is `$pdm_root_dir` in your template path? Or is it a typo?

Comment: Apologies. It's a typo. It's been fixed.

Comment: It looks like it should work. Did you verify the path is correct and the template file can be loaded?

Comment: Yes i did. Also i used the wordpress templating class here in other file: https://github.com/GaryJones/Gamajo-Template-Loader/blob/develop/class-gamajo-template-loader.php could that be a problem?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it working as desired using the condition `is_archive() && get_post_type($post) == 'product'`. I also created a custom taxonomy for `products` as `product-category`

below is the code:

```
function get_custom_post_type_template($archive_template){
    global $post;
    $plugin_root_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/product-plugin/';

    if (is_post_type_archive('product')){
        $archive_template = $plugin_root_dir . '/inc/templates/archive-product.php';
    }
    return $archive_template;
}
add_filter('archive_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template');
```